# How to set up X for own GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, xorg

I'm quite new to linux, raspberry, tkinter and python and therefore I need some guidance to get on the right track.

I'm running Arch Linux on a raspberry pi and I want a quite fast loaded gui for my project. I have decided to go with tkinter. I have installed xorg and some other needed xorg packages, and when I run "startx" I get three windows and a litte clock with some green/blue colored borders and i can move the widows with drag and drop. If I run my tkinter py-file from any window it works just fine.

I came over the "xinit" command and this loads a little faster and just gives me one window without borders. This actually suits me better since my "base window" will work as some kind of desktop and from here I will pop up other windows. Since there's no borders or title bars on the windows, they are not moveable. Is there any way to achieve this? That is, I want just some windows to have a border and a title bar.

And; how can I run the tkinter py-file automatically when I run the xinit/startx? I have tried the other approach by run the xinit/startx in the pyfile, but this does not work. I guess this will be called as some kind of sub command in another thread, or something? Any suggestions how I do this?

Comment: Not sure this is a question about programming -- it's a question about *using* X. That said -- use `~/.xinitrc` to control what gets run when X is started up.

Comment: The difference you see is between having a window manager and not having one. The window manager is what allows you to move, resize, and generally manipulate windows. (The extra apps which are apparently being run from the window manager's start script are obviously optional.)